# Do I need to perform updates when I'm running a Virtual Box inside the host?

Tags: windows, security, virtualbox

I am running Windows XP as the host, and have several flavors of Linux running on the Virtual Box. I'm never going to use my Windows host for anything, other than a host.

Will the Windows machine stand a chance of attack without updates? I do have a firewall installed (don't know if I can mention brands) and a virus scanner - But I refuse the updates and the .NET stuff - as I'm not using the machine for anything.

I know I could just run Linux and do a virtual box inside, but due to circumstances... I am running Windows.

Answer (score 3):

If the computer is connected to the network then you may be vulnerable to security holes in Windows XP itself, e.g. an attack targeting the TCP/IP stack. Even if you don't use it for anything other than a VM host, I'd still recommend keeping Windows as up-to-date as possible, especially if it's connected to the network.

In my opinion, the only time you should avoid keeping an OS updated is if there is an incompatible application that won't run under a particular hotfix, but these should be rare.